# DIvi Theme Builder An unkown error has occurred, please try again later

Tags: php, wordpress, divi-theme

I've been trying to get divi theme builder to work but this error always pops up;

"An unknown error has occurred, please try again later."

I've tried the configurations

```
memory_limit 256M
post_max_size 128M
max_execution_time 300
upload_max_filesize 64M
max_input_time 600
max_input_vars 6000
```

and even upgraded my php to 7.4 but still get the same error

additional info:
Wordpress Version: 5.3.2
Divi version: 4.0.9

Comment: finally solved it by upgrading divi version

Answer (score 2):

I too encountered the same issue today and here is how I solved it.

Step1: Looked at Divi->Support Center at my WordPress Dashboard for any error listings.

[Divi Support Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHsJK.jpg)

Which clearly told that wp-content directory was not writable. To confirm furthermore followed step2.

Step2: Enable WordPress Debug logs in wp-config.php as below:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Now I saw below errors in webserver log files:

```
2020/01/08 10:48:49 [error] 18271#18271: *2598 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: .../cache/Directory.php:65 ET_Core_Cache_Directory::_initialize():
Unable to write to the filesystem. Please ensure that PHP has to write access to one of the following directories:

 - WP_CONTENT_DIR
 - wp_upload_dir()
 - ET_CORE_CACHE_DIR" while reading response header from the upstream, client:
```

It was more or less clear that because of not writable to WP_CONTENT_DIR by the webserver, the timeout occurred. Provided the required permission to the user which is running the webserver (in my case Nginx) as below:

```
#chown <username>:nginx wp-content/
#chmod 775 wp-content
```

Now it started working. Hope this helps. This is because Divi creates a directory called et-cache inside wp-content dir for [performance enhancement by generating static css file](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/theme-releases/divi-performance-enhancement-introducing-static-css-file-generation-for-divi) which is cached in the et-cache folder.

Comment: my case seems to be different since my entire folder had 777 on everything, solved it by updating divi version, it seems to only happen on 4.09, 4.11 ran smoothly

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that the **Post Max Size** and the **Upload Size Limit** has the same values.

Alternatively, I would like to ask how many plugins you have installed in your installation?

Incompatible plugins and/or themes and improperly set file permissions can be a source of this issue.

So, it is recommended that you test out your plugins. Navigate to **Plugins > Installed Plugins** within WordPress. Select the top checkbox next to Plugin (select all plugins except divi) and choose *Deactivate* from the *Bulk Actions* drop-down menu. Click Apply, then return to the page you wanna edit.

If it loads, one of your plugins is the issue. Unfortunately, there’s no easy way to tell which one. You’ll have to reactivate each plugin individually and check your issue each time. Once the issue emerges again, the plugin you’ve just activated is the problem.